# Redeclare class error is coming when I trying to open the login of opencart

Tags: php, content-management-system, e-commerce, opencart, opencart2.x

Does anyone know what can cause of this problem?

```
Cannot redeclare class ControllerCommonHeader in /home/fashion1/public_html/loginpanel/language/english/common/header.php on line 187
```

Actually home directory name is **home2** but in this path shows

```
/**home/**fashion1/public_html/loginpanel/language/english/common/header.php
```

Comment: The message is clear: you have to classes with the same name in your project. One should be removed or changed.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. Actually my doubt is that when I check inside the cpanel / filemanager /Home directory where the the directory name is home2. But in this path showing /home/.